# Como realizar um tipo de href com parâmetros em uma imagem utilizando Ionic / AngularJs

Tags: ionic, ionic2, angular

Tenho este trecho de código, que mostra uma imagem com um CSS por cima:

```
 <img class="imagemCapa" image-lazy-loader="lines" ng-src="{{item.cadastra_oferta_foto}}" />
                    <div class="promocao"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_desconto}}% Off</b></div>
                    <div class="desconto"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto | currency}}</b></div>
```

Gostaria de referenciar esta imagem a um outro $state, como utilizo num botão:

```
 <a class="item button button-clear button-assertive ink" href="#nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">MAIS INFORMAÇÕES</a>
```

Se coloco na classe img, corta a imagem. Tentei ui-sref mas não funciona.

Como posso passar esta url com parametros na imagem e não cortar a imagem?

Aproveitando, segue o CSS da imagem:

```
/* Coloca o desconto na imagem */
.imagemCapa{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
.promocao{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    left: 4%;

    z-index: 300;
    float: left;
    background: #D95B43;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    color: #FFF;

}

.sacola{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 300;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    color: #E81D62;

}
```

EDITADO:

Este trecho do código me mostra uma imagem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além do botão para ir aos detalhes deste produto, gostaria que a imagem também fosse direcionada aos detalhes do produto. No botão utilizo:

```
 <a class="item button button-clear button-assertive ink" href="#nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">MAIS INFORMAÇÕES</a>
```

Mas esta abordagem na imagem não funciona, corta a imagem não mostrando ela toda.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você quer fazer.

Comment: @LINQ editei a pergunta com mais detalhes...

Comment: e deveria ficar como ?

Comment: Vc está dizendo que quando joga a <img> dentro de um <a> a imagem quebra? vc já inspecionou o elemento e tirou as propriedades desse <a> para ver se não é isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode montar dinamicamente(Vindo de algum controller):

```
ui-sref="{{vm.suaVariavel}}({parametro:'valor'})">
```

Ou de forma estática(Nome do estado direto na view)

```
ui-sref="nomeDoEstado({param1: 'valor', param2: 'valor'})" ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}"
```

Coloquei a opção reload true caso seja necessário fazer o recarregamento da página.